# Get Value From Another Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the names of all my worksheets in column B.  I need to get the value of cell G25 from each worksheet name in that column B and display the value in column D. Currently, I have this formula in column D:

```
=B1&"!G25"
```

This problem is the cell outputs: SHEET!G25  and does not show the value of cell G25 from that sheet.

I understand I could just use the formula: =Sheet!G25 to get the value but I need to use the list of worksheet names from column B (so I don't have to enter each worksheet name manually.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks in advance!

This is all in one workbook FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT`

```
=INDIRECT(B1&"!G25")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Indirect function]

Assuming you have this set up in your Sheet1
copy paste this formula in cell C2 up to cells you needed

=INDIRECT(B2&"!"&$D$2,TRUE)

and you can change the worksheet name in column B as you like